# Flutter: How can I show list using listviewbuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to generate this newvoucherlist inside listviewbuilder. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post images as code. Instead, [edit] your question with the code you have already tried, and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

```
ListView.builder( 

        itemCount: newVoucherList.length, 

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){ 

          return myWidget(newVoucherList[index]);
        } 
)

myWidget(newVoucherList){
      // use this newVoucherList here in your widget
}
```